# Migrate existing android app on IBM MobileFirst to IBM Bluemix

Tags: java, android, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

I have a locally created android app on IBM MobileFirst (in Eclipse). Is it possible to either push this existing app+mobilefirst environment to IBM Bluemix OR at least the existing android app to Mobilefirst container/environment in Bluemix?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the difference between the two questions in your question... anyway, you can indeed set-up an IBM container running MobileFirst Server by following this tutorial: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/ibm-containers/run/

You can then upload the .wlapp file to the server running in the container, and latestly - configure the Android app to connect to it.

Comment: As per this blog, it seems Windows 7 is not supported?

Comment: The tooling does not work well with it. You can attempt with the Docker beta.

Comment: I have limited knowledge of Docker, can you please share the steps for the same? Thanks in advance!

Comment: MobileFirst does not support the Docker beta, so you are on your own in that regard.

Comment: Any planned date by which IBM intends to support Windows out of the box?